# VB find out number is mod of which number

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, math, equation, modulo

I'm trying to find the number that gives me the result, here's the equation:

```
x=y mod z  
y=?
```

In this equation, I know values of `x` and `z` but I need to find of `y` too, does anyone has an idea?

Comment: This is not a programming question; it's an algebra question.  Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But as you see the title, I want the code in VB, isn't it programming?

Comment: That's like asking "What is the correct spelling of this word that I'm displaying in a Msgbox in VB?" which would be a spelling question, not a VB question.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a single answer to this question.  There could be many.  For example if `z=5` and `x=1`, then y could be 6, 11,  16, etc.

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions to your problem because mapping integers to values in ring **Zz**  `(z integer numbers: 0, 1, ..., z - 1)` is not a bijection:

```
y = { x + n * z : n is integer }
```

So, the simplest function that will provide you with an answer can be as simple as that:

```
Function solution( ByVal x As Integer) As Integer 
    Return x
End Function
```

You can also write something that will return you next possible solution:

```
Function solution_next( ByVal x As Integer, ByVal z As Integer) As Integer
    Static n As Integer = 0 
    i + z * n
    n += 1
    Return i
End Function
```

You can adjust this further given more conditions.